# Conformal Mapping Function and Scaling Factor

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, scaling

I am having problems determining a scaling factor for a conformal mapping function.

The plan is to map the upper half plane into a rectangle (Schwarz Christoffel Transformation) to determine the values for lumped elements in an equivalent circuit diagram of a coplanar waveguide structure.

The first step would be to map my structure from the original domain into a rectangle in the w-domain. I am doing this by performing a series of conformal mapping steps but here I am already struggling to write code that creates a rectangle in the desired orientation. This is what I have got so far.
This first section is meant to define the geometry of the original structure:

```
pieces = 500;
GP1 = 500*10^(-6);
GP2 = GP1;

RF1 = 240*10^(-6);

GAP1 = 50*10^(-6);
GAP2 = GAP1;
l = 500*10^(-6);
h = 50*10^(-6);
t = 5*10^(-6);
\[Sigma] = 5.8*10^(7)(*[S/m]*);
Rs = 0.015;
\[Epsilon]r = 10;
f = Range[50000000, 100000000, 1000000]; (*[Hz]*)
\[Omega] = 
 f*2*Pi(*[Hz]*);
\[Epsilon]0 = 8.854187817*10^(-12)(*[As/Vm]*);
\[Mu]0 = 1.25663706212*10^-6(*N/A^2*);
c = 299792458(*[m/s]*);
```

After this, I am dividing all the lengths into smaller pieces such that I can get ListPlots that look like the structures. Note: Due to symmetry only one half of the structure is taken into consideration.

```
    zCor = {0, RF1/2, RF1/2 + GAP1, RF1/2 + GAP1 + GP1, 
   RF1/2 + GAP1 + GP1 - h*I, 0 - h*I};

\[Delta]RF = (RF1/2)/(pieces - 1);

zCorRFpieces = Range[0, RF1/2, \[Delta]RF];


\[Delta]GP = GP1/(pieces - 1);
zCorGPpieces = Range[RF1/2 + GAP1, RF1/2 + GAP1 + GP1, \[Delta]GP];

zCorUpper = {{zCorRFpieces, zCorRFpieces + t*I}, {zCorGPpieces, 
    zCorGPpieces + t*I}};

PLOT0 = ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ Flatten[zCorUpper], 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Small}];
Show[PLOT0, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im"}, PlotLabel -> "Z-DOMAIN"]
```

[image: half of the structure in Z-Domain]

After this, I perform three conformal mapping steps:

```
SI1[z_] = z - (First[zCorUpper[[1, 1]]] + Last[zCorUpper[[2, 1]]])/2;
PLOT1 = ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ Flatten[SI1[zCorUpper]], 
   PlotStyle -> Orange, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Small}];
Show[PLOT1, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im"}, PlotLabel -> "SI1-DOMAIN"]
```

[image: SI1-Plane]

```
\[Lambda]1 = SI1[zCorUpper[[2, 1, pieces]]]
\[Alpha]Sol = 
  Solve[0 == \[Lambda]1^2 (SI1[zCorUpper[[1, 1, pieces]]] + 
        SI1[zCorUpper[[2, 1, 1]]])*a^2 + 
     2 (SI1[zCorUpper[[1, 1, pieces]]]*
         SI1[zCorUpper[[2, 1, 1]]] + \[Lambda]1^2)*a + 
     SI1[zCorUpper[[1, 1, pieces]]] + SI1[zCorUpper[[2, 1, 1]]], a];
\[Alpha] = a /. \[Alpha]Sol[[1, 1]]
k0 = (SI1[
    zCorUpper[[2, 1, 
      1]]] + \[Alpha]*\[Lambda]1^2)/(\[Lambda]1 (1 + \[Alpha]*
      SI1[zCorUpper[[2, 1, 1]]]));
SI2[z_] := (
  SI1[z] + \[Alpha]*\[Lambda]1^2)/(\[Lambda]1 (1 + \[Alpha]*
      SI1[z]) k0);

PLOT2 = ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ Flatten[SI2[zCorUpper]], 
   PlotStyle -> Cyan, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Small}];
Show[PLOT2, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im"}, PlotLabel -> "SI2-DOMAIN"]
```

[image: SI2-plane]

```
SI3 = Conjugate[
  I*Simplify[
    Integrate[
     1/((\[Zeta] - 1)^(1/2) (\[Zeta] - 1/k0)^(1/2) (\[Zeta] + 1)^(1/
         2) (\[Zeta] + 1/k0)^(1/2)), {\[Zeta], 0, z}, 
     Assumptions -> {Im[z] > 0}]]]
map = SI3 /. {z -> Flatten[SI2[zCorRFpieces]]};
map2 = SI3 /. {z -> Flatten[SI2[zCorGPpieces]]};

PLOT5 = ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ map, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Small}];
PLOT6 = ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ map2, PlotStyle -> Cyan, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Small}];

Show[PLOT6, PLOT5, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im"}, PlotLabel -> "SI3-DOMAIN"]
```

[image: SI3-plane]

I think could add some clever factors to the SI3[z_] function to map everything inside a rectangle in which the lower side is lying on the Real axis but I do not see how.

Also, I will need to determine a Scaling factor M that relates a differential length in the z-Plane to one in the w-plane such that M=Abs[dw/dz]. I tried this here but without any promising results results

```
W[z_] = SI3[SI2[SI1[z]]];
M[z_] = Abs[D[W[z], z]];
M[SI3[Flatten[zCorUpper]]]
```

This scaling factor will later become a function in an integral integrating along the real axis from 0 to the endpoint of the rectangle.

```
Simplify[
 Integrate[1/(
  I*w*bI*\[Mu]0 + Re[surfaceImpedanceGP[w]]*MSI[u] + 
   Re[surfaceImpedanceRF[w]]*MSI[u + I*b]), {u, 0, a}]
```

a corresponds to the endpoint of the rectangle side on the Real axis and b is the Imaginary part of the other side of the rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps, but Ivanov and Trubetskov's [Handbook](https://books.google.nl/books?id=SR4QI6g1m68C&printsec=frontcover) did have a mapping for a rectangle. This code plots it with a strip in the center: (but you perhaps want an empty waveguide)

```
(*  Ivanovs stripline, in box, OK [example 1.65, p237]               *)
(*                                                                   *)
(*  Note: where Ivanov uses F[z,m], Mathematica uses:                *)
(*                                          EllipticF[ArcSin[z],m]   *)
(*                                                                   *)

Clear["Global`*"] 

w = EllipticF[ ArcSin[s], p]
s = Sqrt[m] JacobiSN[z,m]        (* Re(z)=-2EllipticK[m]...2EllipticK[m],
                                    Im(z)=0...EllipticK[1-m] ???,
                                    but for inductance: bounds of w ?? *)
p=.8925;
m = 0.5

tt = -EllipticE[m]*EllipticK[1-m]/EllipticK[m] -
        Im[ EllipticE[ArcSin[1/Sqrt[m]], m] ]          (*  ???  *)

f[u_] = w /. z->u
g[x_,y_] := {Re[f[x + I y]], Im[f[x + I y]]} / EllipticK[p] 

ParametricPlot[{
                 g[z, 0.2],
                 g[z, 0.5],
                 g[z, 1],
                 g[z, 1.3],
                 g[z, 1.6],
                 g[z, 1.75],
                 g[z, EllipticK[1-m]-.0000001],
               },
       {z,-2EllipticK[m],2EllipticK[m]},
       PlotRange->{{-1,1},{-.7,.7}}, AspectRatio->Automatic]
```

It took me some puzzling to map the notation of the book to Mathematica functions. (I did the same for a lot of other examples in the book. The advantage is that the integrals of the Schwarz-Christoffel Transformation are then already replaced by their analytical results in terms of special functions.) Here's the plot of equipotential curves it gives:

[image: Equipotential lines.]